# emberjs - property fires twice

Tags: ember.js

Why does the "fullName" function in this code execute twice?

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  // these will be supplied by `create`
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
  fullName: function() {
    console.log('Full name function...');
    var firstName = this.get('firstName');
    var lastName = this.get('lastName');
    return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

App.tom = Person.create({
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Dale"
});

App.UsersView = Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'users',
    users: [App.tom]
});
```

Later in google-chrome console:

```
App.tom.set('firstName', 'John')
```

This outputs to log twice.

Comment: Text 'Full name function' is printed twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug, indeed (added a JSFiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/GRvgt/)...

The view is rerendered, and the computed property not cached yet. :-(

Comment: By updating to ember-latest, this is corrected. @see http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/vpHth/

Comment: Thanks, it is a bug, I have just tested it again and it is not working with the stable version (currently 0.9.8.1) but works fine with the ember-latest version.